# how to use environnement variable in cli build

Tags: angular, build, command-line-interface, environment

I'm building my first angular 4 project and I'm trying to make it simple for me. So here is my question:

Is there a way to change the default --output-path depending on the environment ?
in other words I would like  to:

- ng build to export the file in the /dev folder
- and ng build --prod to export the file in the /prod folder.

  can the outDir be modified by the environment.ts ?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the output path with `--output-path=SOME_PATH`. You could add some script to your package.json like this:

```
"builddev" : "ng build --output-path=SOME_PATH"
"buildprod" : "ng build --prod --output-path=SOME_OTHER_PATH"
```

Check the docs [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build).

Comment: excellent !  As I'm completely newbie in angular, I never heard about scripting in the package.json. I will look at that. Thank you Robin ps) I guess the second script should be: "buildprod" :)